# How can I find the maximum value in a vector of tuples?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, tuples, max

Consider:

```
vector<tuple<int, int, char>> array;
for(int i=0; i<m-1; i++)
{
   long long int p;
   cin >> p;
   get<0>(x) = p; // Updated value
   get<1>(x) = get<0>(x); // Real value
   get<2>(x) = 'v';
   array.push_back(x);
}
sort(array.begin(), array.end());
reverse(array.begin(), array.end());
// How can I get the maximum of the second field
// to to element with largest first field
// and then delete the tuple?
```

Suppose I have an array of data type tuple as `int, int, char`.

For example, (5,5,h);(5,2,h);(5,7,v);( 3,1,h);(3,7,h);(1,1,v).

It is already sorted in descending order based on the first value. Now I want to find the part that contains largest first value with the largest second value? so i do have to search in the first three part only.
Is there a way to use max() here or any other STL functions?

Comment: From what I see, you didn't sort on first value only; you sorted on the whole tuple. Isn't that so?

Answer (score 1):

`std::tuple::operator <` performs a lexicographical comparison ([Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/operators/)). That means, that after the `sort` and `reverse` the 0th item of `array` contains the `tuple` with the largest third element among all the tuples with the largest second element among all the tuples with the largest first element, which is what you need.

So, just return `array[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

As the default `operator <` is good, you may simply use

```
const std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, char>> tuples = // ...

auto it = std::max_element(tuples.begin(), tuples.end());
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/7cS2n6)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the third tuple element used in the compression, and you not want to use sort and reverse functions, I think is good choice to use `std::max_element` with lambda such as below:

```
typedef tuple<int, int,char> ET;

auto comparator = [](ET a, ET b)
{
   return std::tie(get<0>(a), get<1>(a)) < std::tie(get<0>(b), get<1>(b))
}
```